# Javascript send metadata with zip file in xhttp POST request

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to upload zip-files with metadata like a title and certain number.

Either I'm sending the zip file directly with:

```
function generalPostRequest(content, url, cb) {    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.withCredentials = true;
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("NAME:PASS"));

    //DIFF
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
    //DIFF

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
            if (cb) {
                cb(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.send(content);//DIFF
}
```

But then I don't know how to add metadata.
The other way would be:

```
function generalPostRequest(content, url, cb) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.withCredentials = true;
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("NAME:PASS"));

    //DIFF
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    var params = JSON.stringify(content);
    //DIFF

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
            if (cb) {
                cb(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.send(params);//DIFF
}
```

But if I add the zip into an array, the JSON.stringify function removes the zip file. I probably have to convert it into a byte array.

How do I add metadata to solution 1 or how do I convert a zip to a byte array in solution 2?

Comment: What "kind" of meta data? Where is the documentation that says you need to send this meta data? Best guess, you will be adding a custom header like the `Authorization` and `Content-Type` ones, but need to see the docs first.

Comment: I'd like to send a zip-file, a number and a string all in one POST-request. There is no doc.

Comment: You need to use `FormData`. See: [demo / sample / docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I haven't actually tested this, and since I don't know exactly what kind of value `content` holds, it is difficult to construct a proper test case anyway*.

You are trying to send a JSON file and a Zip file in one request. The way to do that is with a multipart request.

`XMLHttpRequest` can construct a multipart request from a `FormData` object.

You just need to create one and feed it the right data.

```
var zip_data = get_zip_data();
var json_data = get_json_data();

var zip_file = new File(zip_data, "example.zip", { type: "application/zip" });
var json_file = new File(json_data, "example.json", { type: "application/json" });

var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("zip", zip_file, "example.zip");
form_data.append("json", json_file, "example.json");

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", url);
xhttp.withCredentials = true;
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("NAME:PASS"));
xhttp.addEventListener("load", load_handler);
xhttp.send(form_data);

function load_handler() {
    if (cb) {
        cb(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
    }
}
```

Note that you **must not** set the Content-Type header. XHR will generate it from the `FormData` object automatically (and it has to do this as it needs to generate boundry markers between the files).

This should result in the two files being sent to the server as if you had picked them with `<input type="file">` in a regular form. Write the server side code accordingly (e.g. use `$_FILES` if you are using PHP or something like multer if you are using Node.js).

Comment: Thank you a bunch.